# Nokia phone has pre-installed survey: how can I remove it?

Tags: bloatware, nokia-6.1

I just bought a Nokia 6.1 phone. On the whole I like it, but today this popped up:

[image]

The app is called "NPS" ("Net Promoter Score"?) version 9.0010.50. I found a discussion of it [here](https://community.phones.nokia.com/discussion/2793/nps-service), but the only way mentioned to disable it doesn't work (my "User Experience Program/Diagnostic Report" option is already off).

I don't like my time being wasted, but I like even less the idea that the phone is "phoning home" to yet another company.

Any suggestions for how to disable or get rid of this app? (I'm tempted to respond as negatively as possible to every question the app poses...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are familiar with [adb](http://adbshell.com/) and the command prompt you can remove any apps including system apps with this command:

`adb shell pm uninstall --user 0 com.evenwell.nps`

com.evenwell.nps is the package name, you can see every app's package name with an app like APK Manager or Package Manager, etc
Comfirmed successfully done on my nokia 6.1 
I do this for several system apps that I don't have any use for so they don't use my battery unnecessarily, just obviously do not delete anything if you do not know for sure what it is there are things that may look strange or unneeded that are actually there in order for the device to run and you can ruin your phone. Upon factory reset, all things are reinstalled normally.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does this require a jailbroken phone?

Comment: @DanielGriscom in Android world, the term is a rooted phone, not jailbroken. :) And no, the device need not be rooted because of the argument `--user 0` which effectively removes the app only for the user account 0 (primary account / administrator), not from the whole device per se. If you factory reset, the app would come back again.

Comment: Excellent info: thanks.